# visual studio code auto fill file content

Tags: visual-studio-code

is it possible to make vsc fill my file with content that i specify when i create a new file? for example:

When I create a file called `something.js`, I want VSC to auto fill these lines of code into the fill:

```js
const mymodule = require(...)
const something = "something"
```

its the same as creating a `.html` file and typing `!` so that VSC will automatically type the required html stuff

Comment: You can't do that from VSC....

Comment: create a snippet for the JavaScript language and use the [variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_variables) and the transforms